# Does Arkit update constantly the mesh of a Reconstructed Scene or can it be static?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit, mesh

Similarly, is it possible to disable mesh update of a reconstructed scene ? I'm new to Arkit and have not started an app yet. I'm searching for as much info as possible. When we want to reconstruct a scene with a mesh, does ARKit keep updating the mesh after the fact or it is "Read-only" and the it stays how it is.

Answer (score 0):

The mesh is constantly updated in the session itself.

If you want to do something with the Mesh, you can get the MeshAnchors from the session.

```
let meshAnchors = arView.session.currentFrame?.anchors.compactMap({ $0 as? ARMeshAnchor })
```

The above code lets you access the MeshAnchor at the current frame.